# How to find an element inside another element in mootools

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

Let's say i need to find all `.bar` elements inside an element that's assigned to a variable `foo`.

In jQuery, `foo.find('.bar')` solves the problem.

What's the equivalent function in mooTools?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="elems">...</span>
    <span class="elems">...</span>
    ...
</div>

----

var elems = $('container').getElements('.elems');
// elems is now an array containing all spans with the class 'elem'
```

Or:

```
var elems = $$('#container.elems');
```

Comment: +1 Sorry to nitpick but shouldn't it be: var elems = $$('#container .elems'); instead?